# ASP.Net MVC Routing URL Generation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Html.ActionLink appends "Index", the action name to the end of the urls, but i would like to not have the index action listed in the default controller url (hope that makes some sense...)

Not Wanted: /ControllerName/Index
WANTED:  /ControllerName

Below is my routing setup:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                null,
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                null,
                new { id = @"\d+" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                null,
                "{controller}/{action}"
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                null,
                "{controller}",
                new { action = "Index" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                null,
                "",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );
```

Comment: my Html.ActionLinks that go to index, don't append index onto the link... even though i supply "Index" as the target action it just links to /ControllerName

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flip them all around.  The routes, as you've listed them, should be in the reverse order you've listed them in.

Comment: Thanks, why am I not surprised that its something so simple?

Comment: Yes, you're right, thats possible (just deleted my answer). Defining an action as a default one can be usefull in that example. +1